# Django view: How to display data from a dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I've got a dictionary like `{'a':{'c':2, 'd':4 }, 'b': {'c':'value', 'd': 3}}`

How can I display this into a table in view?

Comment: Recursive custom template tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you want to do it. In Django templates, you access keys the same way you access a method. That is, Python code like

```
print my_dict['a']['c']    # Outputs: 2
```

becomes

```
{{ my_dict.a.c }}    {# Outputs: 2 #}
```

in Django templates.

Comment: it looks the my_dict.iteritems() in template doesn't work? How can I iterate through?

Comment: @Mike: Iterating over a `dict` yields keys.

Comment: D'oh, it's late.  I meant `{% for key, item in my_dict.items %}`.

Answer (score 3):

Question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template):

In summary you access the code as you would for a python dictionary

```
data = {'a': [ [1, 2] ], 'b': [ [3, 4] ],'c':[ [5,6]] }
```

You can use the dict.items() method to get the dictionary elements:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
</tr>

{% for key, values in data.items %}
<tr>
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    {% for v in values[0] %}
    <td>{{v}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem and I solved it this way

PYTHON

```
views.py
#I had a dictionary with the next structure
my_dict = {'a':{'k1':'v1'}, 'b':{'k2': 'v2'}, 'c':{'k3':'v3'}}
context = {'renderdict': my_dict}
return render(request, 'whatever.html', context)
```

HTML

```
{% for key, value in renderdict.items %}
    <h1>{{ key }}</h1>
    
    {% for k, v in value.items %}
      <h1>{{ k }}</h1>
      <h1 > {{ v }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

The outputs would be 
{{ key }} = a 
{{ k }} = k1 
{{ v }} = v1  #and so forth through the loop.
```