# django template nested dictionary, grab value by key

Tags: python, html, django, templates

In a django template, if I have a key within the context dictionary assocoated with another dictionary (a nested dictionary), I know how to itterate over it ([how to iterate through dictionary in a dictionary in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template)) but I need to find a value by key.

like `{{ nested_dictionary['key'] }}`

But I'm guessing not exactly that...

Filters could be used, but is there a better way?

Comment: Filters are the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8000091/1267329

Comment: hmmm ok thanks, seems like theres room for this to be a lot easier...

Comment: You can always write a custom template tag to do it. Generally I prefer to avoid this kind of data structure in my context, though.

Comment: Have you tried {{ nested_dictionary.key }} ?

Comment: Right, dot syntax works if the key is known when you're writing the template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have a nested dictionary in your view i.e.:

```
...
dashTable = {'Key0':{'Key1':{'Key2':{'Key3':5}}}}

context = {'dashTable':dashTable,}
return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Then you would be able to call your nested dictionary when passed through as context with:

```
{{ dashTable.Key0.Key1.Key2.Key3 }}
```