# how to iterate through a dict

Tags: python, django

I want to show this piece of data in template table

```
{u'User1': {'annual_spend__sum': None}, u'User2': {'annual_spend__sum': 80}, u'User3': {'annual_spend__sum': 30}, u'User4': {'annual_spend__sum': None}}
```

I am not sure how to loop over the data to show it properly can anyone help?

```
this_user = User.objects.get(id=3)
    all_users = User.objects.all()
    values = {}
    for this_user in all_users:
        values[this_user.username] = Lead.objects.filter(assign_to=this_user).exclude(lead_status='CV').aggregate(Sum('annual_spend'))
    values.items()


    return render(request, 'index.html', {'annual_spend': values})
```

**Updated**

```
def func(request):
    from django.template import context
    this_user = User.objects.get(id=3)
    all_users = User.objects.all()

    values = {}
    for this_user in all_users:
        values[this_user.username] = Lead.objects.filter(assign_to=this_user).exclude(lead_status='CV').aggregate(Sum('annual_spend'))

    context = {}
    annual_spend__sum_list = []
    data = values

    for i in data:
        annual_spend__sum_list.append(data[i]['annual_spend__sum'])

    context['result'] = annual_spend__sum_list

    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

**Template**

```
<ul>
{% for i in result %}
<li>{{ i }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to iterate through dictionary in a dictionary in django template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template)

Comment: Duplicate is just one of many links found on google by searching for "django iterate dict"....

Comment: @Sayse I don't want to be rude,  but that topic didn't answer my question.

Comment: What is your question then? From what I can tell you are looking to iterate over a dictionary (`annual_spend`) in a template. what have you tried/researched?

Comment: @Sayse Yes basically what I want to do is show the the data in the template so it looks something like this http://codepad.org/jkenMTTG

Comment: That is what the duplicate does.

Comment: @Sayse please elaborate

Answer (score -1):

Just iterate through it like any other dictionary.

```
data = {'User1': {'annual_spend__sum': None}, 'User2': {'annual_spend__sum': 80}, 'User3': {'annual_spend__sum': 30}, 'User4': {'annual_spend__sum': None}}

for i in data:
    print i, data[i], data[i]['annual_spend__sum']
```

This is the output:

```
>>> data = {'User1': {'annual_spend__sum': None}, 'User2': {'annual_spend__sum': 80}, 'User3': {'annual_spend__sum': 30}, 'User4': {'annual_spend__sum': None}}
>>> 
>>> for i in data:
...     print i, data[i], data[i]['annual_spend__sum']
... 
User4 {'annual_spend__sum': None} None
User2 {'annual_spend__sum': 80} 80
User3 {'annual_spend__sum': 30} 30
User1 {'annual_spend__sum': None} None
>>>
```

Now, you can do whatever you want with it.

I suggest that you make a context dict and put a `list` of `annual_spend__sum` in it and then pass it to the `render`.

Do it like this:

```
def func(request):
    context = {}
    annual_spend__sum_list = []
    data = {'User1': {'annual_spend__sum': None}, 'User2': {'annual_spend__sum': 80}, 'User3': {'annual_spend__sum': 30}, 'User4': {'annual_spend__sum': None}}

    for i in data:
        annual_spend__sum_list.append(data[i]['annual_spend__sum'])

    context['result'] = annual_spend__sum_list

    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

Now, in index.html you can print like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for i in result %}
        <li>{{ i }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can do it in a lot of different ways. This was the most basic and easiest to explain. See in `for` loop, I directly referred to the key and iterated through the results.

Comment: thank for your help, can I ask what will the context dict will do?

Comment: doesn't seem to work but in terminal I get same output but when I try to show it on the template nothing.

Comment: Then there's something wrong with how you are using it in template. Can't help you there unless you show more code.

Comment: I updated the original post check it out, that is how I did everything.

Comment: @ohhellothere where's index.html?

Comment: @ Abhyudit Jain I added the code I used in the template

Comment: @ohhellothere does the template open? Try printing some random values

Comment: @ohhellothere can you post a screenshot? I really don't see the problem. It works fine in my project.

Comment: I got an error 'dict' object has no attribute 'push'

Comment: @ohhellothere Why are you returning render and then other dict? everything should go in context.