# Loop through a defaultdict(list) structure in a django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a structure `my_dict` like this:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
   <MyClass: myobject1>: [<ThingClass: mything1>, <ThingClass: mything2>, ...],
   <MyClass: myobject2>: [<ThingClass: mything6>, <ThingClass: mything7>, ...], 
   <MyClass: myobject3>: [<ThingClass: mything45>, <ThingClass: mything46>, ...],
   ...
})
```

I want to loop through the objects something like this:

```
{% for object in my_dict %}
    {{object.somefield}}    
      {% for thing in object %}
          {{thing.somefield}}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

How do I loop through the things in this nested loop? myobject1 is not iterable, so how do I get the iterable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should loop through `.items()` of the dictionary to get both object and the list in hand at each iteration:

```
{% for obj, things in my_dict.items %}
    {{obj.somefield}}

    {% for thing in things %}
        {{thing.somefield}}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks.  If I pass `my_dict` in the context and try to get `my_dict.items` in the template, it fails:`{{my_dict.items}} = []` but I tried passing `my_dict.items()` in the context, and it works?! I don't understand.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template 

I am not able to make more comments as I don't know what else you are doing in the template and the view.