# Django template not displaying looped keys, values

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm very new to Django and am trying to figure out why I can call the keys in a dict in my template as expected, but looping through the dict does not produce any text, nor any error messages. I don't want to hard code the key names (i.e. below `msgid` in my template, because the dict is dynamic and so I only want to loop through it.

**views.py**

```
class Pymat_program(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        selected_xml = 'a_directory_to_my_file'
        smsreport_dict = self.parse_xml_file(selected_xml)
        html = self.populate_html_text(smsreport_dict)

        return HttpResponse(html)

    def populate_html_text(self, smsreport_dict):
        t = get_template('template2.html')
        html = t.render(smsreport_dict)

        return html
```

**template2.html**

```
    <p>MSGID: {{ msgid }}</p>

    <p> Begin
    {% for key, value in smsreport_dict %}
        <tr>
            <td> Key: {{ key }} </td> 
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </p>End
```

In the template2.html you can see the msgid value (one of several values in smsreport_dict) being called, which is displayed on my page. But for some reason the smsreport_dict looping produces no text. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try `t.render(context={'smsreport_dict':smsreport_dict})` in your method `populate_html_text`.

Comment: @ Jens, ozgur: the resolve was a combination of both your answers. I needed to add items in my template, plus context={'smsreport_dict':smsreport_dict}. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`smsreport_dict` should be inside the [`Context`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) you use in order to render the template:

```
...
html = t.render(Context({"smsreport_dict": smsreport_dict}))
...
```

Plus, you forgot to call `.items` when iterating through the dict in the template:

```
{% for key, value in smsreport_dict.items %}
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.items` to `smsreport_dict`

> MSGID: {{ msgid }}

```
<p> Begin
{% for key, value in smsreport_dict.items %}
    <tr>
        <td> Key: {{ key }} </td> 
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</p>End
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template) for a similar situation.