# Django - formating/accessing a Pandas.to_dict() dataframe in a Template

Tags: python, django, pandas, dictionary, django-templates

How do I access this type of dictionary (a dictionary within a dictionary) in a Django template?

I would like to highly customize a DataFrame generated by Pandas in a Django view/template.  I'm able to generate the dictionary that I would like to render, but accessing the elements using template tags has proven difficult.

Here is an example of the dictionary:

```
df_dict =
  {
  ('Key1', 'Key2'): {
            'Line 1': '', 
            'Line 2': '', 
            'Line 3': 53000.0, 
            'Line 4': -120000.0, 
            'Line 5': 45000.0
            }, 
  ('Key3', 'Key2'): {
            'Line 1': '', 
            'Line 2': 100.0, 
            'Line 3': '', 
            'Line 4': '', 
            'Line 5': ''
            }, 
  ('Key4', 'Key2'): {
            'Line 1': 1000.0, 
            'Line 2': '', 
            'Line 3': 2000.0, 
            'Line 4': '', 
            'Line 5': ''
            }
  }
```

My desired template output (without regard to css formatting) is:

```
           Key1       Key3     Key4
           Key2       Key2     Key2         
Line 1                         1000
Line 2                100   
Line 3     53000               2000
Line 4     -120000      
Line 5     45000
```

I've tired a simple template tag to iterate over the dictionary like this:

```
{% for key, value in object %}
    <li>{{key}} : {{value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

but it only provides for:

```
Key1 : Key2
Key3 : Key2
Key4 : Key2
```

I can't figure out how to get into the dictionary that is the value for the above key pairs.  I've also worked through countless .dot notation tags without any luck.

I've also looked other libraries that will render 'nice' html, but I would like to further customize with `bootstrap`.  I've also looked at [wenzhixin](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table)'s solution, but I would like a more flexibility.

### Update for Data Structure

The information is obviously from a QuerySet, but in order to merge and pivot from multiple models, I've used Pandas.  Once the dataframe is appropriately built and formatted, I've used the `df_dict.to_dict()` method (where `df_dict` is my dataframe) and then passed that into the context dictionary.  Basically:

```
context = {
    #stuff,
    'df_dict': df_dict,
    #more stuff,
    }

return context
```

The structure I've shown is simple - it is for more likely that the column index will have three or more keys.  The values size and design will be constant by design (in other words, every key group will have 5 lines of the value dictionary, or 19 lines in the value dictionary).

Final note where @ScottSkiles closed the gap - SO Question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template) starts out using a dictionary within a dictionary, but the answer at the very end using the template example omits the `.items` method in the template and the dataset is a list.  But the below answer is appropriately applied.

Comment: What is the hashable object in the dictionary? Is it the tuple? If possible, you should try to do as much pre-processing before you pass the dictionary to the template via the context. What does your view look like where you're passing the dict to the context?

Comment: If you just want to render a pandas DataFrame you might want to look into django-tables2: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @ScottSkiles, I hadn't run across `django-tables2`.  Looking at that now.

Comment: @ScottSkiles, `django-tables2`, IIUC takes a django queryset object as its argument.  I can't get the right data using a queryset, so I'm using a Pandas DF.

Comment: ```Its features include: Any iterable can be a data-source, but special support for Django querysets is included.```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to iterate through dictionary in a dictionary in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template)

Comment: This might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template

Comment: @ScottSkiles - i saw this SO item, and that was the iteration I tried above...  the question started the same...  but didn't seem to address a dictionary as an actual value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173503/discussion-between-scott-skiles-and-bill-armstrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for key, values in object.items %}
    <li>{{key}} : 
    <ul>
    {% for value in values %} 
        <li>{{value.name}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

via: [how to iterate through dictionary in a dictionary in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template)