# How to use variable in for loop using DJango

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

I can do this in regular python, but can't seem to do this in the template.

So here are my variables:

```
PropertyID = ['A1','A2','A3']
filePaths = {A1:'['file1.jpg','file2.jpg','file3.jpg',]', A2:'['file1.jpg','file2.jpg','file3.jpg']'}
```

My template:

```
{% for properties in PropertyID %}
  {% for filePaths in imageFiles %}
    {% for singleFiles in filePaths %}

       

    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to be able to iterate through filePaths dynamically, but when I try:

```
{% for singleFiles in filePaths.{{properties}} %}
```

I get an error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '{{properties}}' from 'filePaths.{{properties}}'

I have tried filePaths['properties'] and filePaths[properties] and pretty much every combination.  I just can't figure out why this isn't working.

If I do filePaths.A1 it works fine, but I can't iterate over the rest of the paths this way.

Any help would be much appreciated, probably something really dumb I missed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to iterate through dictionary in a dictionary in django template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018973/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-in-a-dictionary-in-django-template)

Comment: Drop the curly brackets!

Comment: I think what you need is a custom template filter.

Comment: I tried dropping the curly brackets, but "properties" is not an attribute of filePaths, so that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access dictionary keys like that, instead you can use [`{% if %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if) logic in the teample:

```
{% for properties in PropertyID %}
  {% for filePaths in imageFiles %}
    {% for propertyKey, singleFiles in filePaths.items %}
        {% if propertyKey == properties %}
           {% for singleFile in singleFiles %}
             // your code
           {% endfor %}
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

FYI, it is better to do these operations in views instead of templates.